# my code is not seeing a class variable (object)? when calling a different function within the same class

Tags: python, function, class

i am currently creating a python program using pygame. And am currently writing a class that ticks to see if any objects is in range.

this is the call within the program loop, it wants me to pass through the classname which i shouldnt have to do..... right?

```
self.AuraDetection([cat.pos, mouse.pos], cat, mouse)
```

Below is the function, the self.counter variable is not being recognised, even if the initlization of the variable is within the class INIT function.

```
    def AuraDetection(self, animals, cat, mouse):
    if abs(animals[0][0] - animals[1][0]) <= 150 and abs(animals[0][1] - animals[1][1]) <= 150 and self.counter == 0:
        cat.StateChange()
        self.counter = 1
```

Here is the init function

```
 def __init__(self):
    super(self)
    screen = pg.display.get_surface()
    self.width = 800
    self.height = 600
    self.fps = 60
    self.counter = 0
```

all of these are within the same class.

https://github.com/freercurse/Boids/blob/master/main.py

here is a link to all of the code within this file, if you want a whole look

Comment: You are calling it wrong. `main.start(main)` should be `main().start()`

Comment: thanks a bunch, fixed everything :)